# Google Marketplace App does not show up in Universal Navigation Bar

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I have created a test app in my test gapps domain:: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gedaikibdebnmndoobklanhdmclpmmdi

The app has gdrive extension enabled, I have marked it Unlisted, so it can be installed with a link. The app shows up fine in the same domain as the app project, both in Universal Navigation Bar and "Open With" Gdrive menu.

When I install the app on my prod domain using the link, the app gets installed, but it never shows up in the Universal Navigation bar - I have waited for more than 24 hours, cleared cache, tried different browsers etc. It however shows up in drive "Open With" menu immediately.

Please help!

Thanks
Sachin

Comment: Is the installed app visibility switched on for the test google apps domain ?

Comment: How do you switch on the visibility?